# codeigniter DOMPDF showing blank screen, no errors, html generating properly but pdf not generating

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, dompdf

In codeigniter,

DOMPDF **showing blank screen**..

**no errors** (in development mode)..

**html generating properly**..

but **pdf not generating**.. only blank screen is there

My Code Snippet:

```
function pdf_create($html, $filename='', $stream=TRUE) 
{
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'potrait');
    $dompdf->render();
    if ($stream) {
        $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
    } else {
        return $dompdf->output();
    }
}

function invoicepdf()
{ 
    $orderId  = base64_decode($this->uri->segment('3'));        
    $this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `ci_booking` WHERE id='".$orderId."'";
    $this->data['order_details'] = $this->home->customQuery($query);

    $html = $this->load->view('reports/printinvoice', $this->data, true);

    //echo $html; die;
    $this->pdf_create($html, 'Invoice -'.$orderId);      
}
```

When I un-comment echo statement of invoicepdf() function.. then output generating properly. but when it passes to pdf_create() function then its showing blank screen, no errors after setting ini_reporting to 1.

**I have attached blank screen inspect code, why its showing like this?**

please suggest me the changes.[image]

Comment: Try these lines of codes: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to show also the warnings

Comment: I am inserting those lines after "require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");" statement though its not showing any kind of warning.. notice.. error

Comment: try returning the output `return pdf_create($html, 'Invoice -'.$orderId);`

Comment: though not working

Comment: plz check attached image when i inspect blank screen

Comment: it looks like your hoster redirects you to some "blank" page... i suspect your way of including your dompdf config is the mistake ... try something like `if (file_exists('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php')) require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php"); else { echo 'dompdf config file missing'; die;}`

Comment: Is both methods written in helper or in a controller? If both written in a controller. `pdf_create` function should be called like `$this->pdf_create`

Comment: yes its going to that function "pdf_create()".. even when i added if(file_exists()).. condition.. then inspect page also getting blank

Comment: you should add those error reporting functions suggested by @GiacomoM inside `invoicepdf` function.

Comment: but sir.. when i uncomment the commented line of invoicepdf() function (//echo $html; die;).. then its showing proper output in html format

Comment: i also tried.. error reporting functions before $this->pdf_creat().. but showing blank screen.. inspect is also blank

Comment: yah.. when i added if(file_exists()).. condition.. then its giving "dompdf config file missing" .. but that file present in helpers

Comment: You mean to say, you have `dompdf` directory inside `helpers` directory and inside `dompdf` directory you have `dompdf_config.inc.php` file? Correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197929/discussion-between-jagad89-and-anjali-patil).

Comment: DomPDF is rather sensible to errors and typos. Note that there's one of those here: `$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'potrait');`. Try changing that to `$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');`. It's very possible that since DomPDF doesn't know what "potrait" is, it's not being able to build the PDF

Comment: Also, please note that javascript is rendered in the browser. DomPDF doesn't render the HTML in a browser DOM engine before writing to the PDF file so, since all readable text in your view comes from a JS `document.write` function, it's not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

There's two issues with your code:

**1.- A small typo that goes a long way:**

You're setting a paper orientation which is unknown to DomPDF here `$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'potrait');` you need to change that to `portrait` or DomPDF may not really understand what you want and fail to render.

**2.- All the human-readable text (not HTML formatting) in your view is being generated with Javascript**, which requires a browser rendering engine that DomPDF doesn't have (DomPDF renders server-side, not client-side, which is important to consider).

The fact that everything works fine when loading the view in the browser is because in that case your browser handles the `document.write` correctly. DomPDF however does not (because it's not a real DOM/JS rendering engine, it just formats a plain HTML in a way that fits in a given paper size and orientation).

Try making the text a regular non-JS HTML

Answer (score 0):

Its solved.. thanks to everyone for help.. it was totally layout issue..wrong colspan was number was there in view file